# Containerize a .net framework 4.5.1 mvc template app give error on permissions

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, docker, .net-4.0

I am trying to containerize in Windows Container a .net framework 4.5.1 MVC application.
I created a template application as VS creates it , without change anything. I publish the app and tried on my windows locall iis server and runs ok.
Then i tried to put in container with the following Dockerfile:

```
    # Build stage
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/sdk:4.8-windowsservercore-ltsc2019 as build
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app 
RUN msbuild netapp451.sln /p:Configuration=Release /p:OutDir=C:\app\bin

RUN dir
WORKDIR /app/bin/

# Runtime stage
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/aspnet:4.8-windowsservercore-ltsc2019 as final

COPY --from=build /app/bin/ /inetpub/wwwroot

EXPOSE 80
```

The image successfully builted. I run it with `docker run -d -p 8082:80 test4511`.
in my browser i enter HTTP://localhost:8082 and i get

```
403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.
You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied.
```

Comment: The aspnet image does not contain an IIS. The aspnet image is meant for apps that use Kestrel. There is an IIS image available that you can use if you want to host your app using IIS.